# Pytorch: turning a [1,x] sized tensor into an [x] sized tensor

Tags: numpy, pytorch

While trying to load in Pytorch 0.4.0 a model that has probably been produced by Pytorch 0.3.1, I keep getting such errors:

```
While copying the parameter named "conv1_7x7_s2_bn.bias", whose dimensions in the
model are torch.Size([64]) and whose dimensions in the checkpoint are torch.Size([1, 64]).
```

I thought that if I had applied `transpose` on each tensor, then it would work, but it is still failing, as the dimension turns into `[64, 1]`, rather than `[64]`, which I need.

I can I remove the redundant dimension and thus turn the 1-row matrix into a vector?

**Note**: When calling `torch.flatten`, I get:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'flatten'
```

Comment: Have you tried `torch.squeeze()`?

Comment: @NilsWerner Thanks, it worked! I suggest that you write it as an answer, so I can accept it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing empty dimensions is called "squeezing". [NumPy does it](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html), [Tensorflow does it](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) and [PyTorch does it](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.squeeze).

So the correct command is:

```
torch.squeeze(tensor)
```